# How to push/pull multiple files to/from Android with ADB using Powershell on Windows?

Tags: android, powershell, push, wildcard, pull

I need to specifically use Windows 10 Powershell, not gitbash or cygwin or CMD, as other answers on SO have provided. I need to be able to use wildcards. I need to be able to push from Windows to Android to a specific folder using wildcards (not entire folder at a time as other answers on SO have provided).

```
Ex: adb push *.png /sdcard/Android/data/myapp/files
Ex: adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/myapp/files/h*.txt
```

Apologies if this has been answered, I have yet to find this specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage loops in powershell to call adb command separately for each file.  Get the files you want to push or pull, loop through and call adb for each.

```
$adb = 'C:\temp\platform-tools\adb.exe'
$local = 'C:\temp\testfiles'
$remote = '/sdcard/Android/data/myapp/files'

function push-adbfiles {
    param ()
    # use Get-ChildItem to capture which files to push
    $files = Get-ChildItem -file $local\*.png

    # loop using ForEach-Object and call adb push command for each
    $files | ForEach-Object {
        & $adb push $_ $remote 
    } 
}


function pull-adbfiles {
    param ()
    # use nix find command to find and return full path of matching files
    $files = & $adb shell find "$remote/h*"

    # loop through files running adb pull on each
    $files | ForEach-Object {
        & $adb pull $_ $local
    }
}
```